# why "HelloWorld" in VS (cocos2d-x) is not operating?

Tags: cocos2d-x, win64

I'm using Win 10 (64 bit). When I tried to operate "HelloWorld" in proj.win10, succeed in build but fail in debuging.
But trying "HelloWorld" in proj.win32, building and debuging are going well.

I'm working on making a simple mobile game.

[image: something goes wrong when I debug HelloWorld in proj.win10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For launching proj.win10 you should have Visual Studio 15.

> Visual Studio 2015 (Release version) and Windows 10.0 (Release
>   version) are required for Windows 10.0 Universal Windows Platform
>   (UWP) Apps. RC versions of Visual Studio and Windows 10 are no longer
>   supported.

Latest version of Cocos is also required:

> Starting with Cocos2d-x v3.8 you can create Windows 10.0 UWP Apps
>   (Windows Store and Windows Phone 10.0). Starting with Cocos2d-x v3.6
>   there will no longer be support for Windows Phone 8.0.

[More info...](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x)